# Get exe file into the build output directory

Tags: .net, visual-studio, winscp, winscp-net

Using WinSCP .NETassembly for SFTP support from a C# program. When building my project in Visual Studio, I would like `WinSCP.exe` and `WinSCPnet.dll` to be copied to the `bin` output directory. `WinSCPnet.dll` is easy enough - as its added as an assembly reference, just set *"Copy Local"* to true, and its done.

But what about `WinSCP.exe`?

Two things I can think of:

1. add the file `WinSCP.exe` to the root of the project, and set *"Copy To Output Directory"* to *"Copy always"*.
2. in project properties *Build Events*, use post-build event command line to copy the file using command line `copy` command.

Both seem a bit clunky. Is there a better way?

Comment: Try msbuild task. Like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394276/msbuild-task-from-csproj-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 1. is the correct approach. Except that you want *"Copy if newer"*. I do not see anything "clunky" about it.

---

Quoting [WinSCP documentation for using the assembly in Visual Studio](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install#vs):

> You may want to add `winscp.exe` to your Visual Studio project, to have it copied to the *Output path* automatically (by setting file property *Copy to Output Directory* to *Copy if newer*). The *Build Action* should be automatically set to *Content*, what means that the file will be included when deploying your application (e.g. an ASP.NET web application or Azure WebJob application).

---

You actually better [install the assembly via NuGet package](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install#nuget).

[WinSCP NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WinSCP/) takes care of these settings itself.