# When using WinSCPnet from NuGet, how can I get the executable into a custom output directory without a duplicate of the exe?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, setup-project, winscp, winscp-net

I'm using the WinSCPnet NuGet package in Visual Studio (.NET Windows Service, with a Setup Project) and have no issue with getting the WinSCPnet DLL into a bin directory in my custom output folder, but getting the WinSCP executable into the same directory is a problem. The closest I've gotten is by following the WinSCP guidance [here](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install#vs), but this results in a copy of the executable in my root output directory AND another copy in my bin directory.

Already followed the directions [here](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install#vs) and referenced a related item [here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43246318/get-exe-file-into-the-build-output-directory)

My steps:

1. Install WinSCPnet NuGet package
2. Manually copy the WinSCP executable into my project and set the "Copy to Output Directory" parameter to "Copy if Newer"
3. Set the write directory for the "Content" output in my setup project (Content placeholder is in the "bin" directory)
4. Build setup project (and dependencies)
5. Install the published MSI
6. The WinSCP.exe executable appears in the root install directory as well as the "bin" directory.
7. The installed service is twice the size it needs to be because of two instances of the WinSCP executable.

Can anyone offer guidance on this?

Comment: I do not understand why are you adding another copy of `winscp.exe` to your project.

Comment: Martin, I want all my application's supporting DLLs to be in the "bin" directory inside the install directory. Even though I place winscpnet.dll into my "bin" directory in my install project, the WinSCP xecutable is being copied to the install directory and not the "bin" directory. I added the second copy to my project because it was unclear if having an explicit reference to the executable would prevent it being automatically copied to my install directory. It is clear that it does not.

Comment: The core of my question is, how do I get WinSCP.exe into my "bin" directory WITHOUT adding a second copy?

Comment: WinSCP NuGet package [takes care of adding `WinSCP.exe` to the `bin` folder](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install#nuget). You do not need to do anything.

Comment: Martin, I appreciate you taking the time to reply - but I wouldn't be raising this question if that's what was actually happening. When I build my Setup Project, I have "WinSCPnet.dll" in my "bin" folder. When I install my project, "WinSCPnet.dll" is in my "bin" folder, "WinSCP.exe" is in the root of the install directory.

Comment: Then we need [mcve] to reproduce the issue. When I create a new console C# project in VS and add WinSCP NuGet package, with no other change, after build both  `WinSCP.exe` and `WinSCPnet.dll` end in `bin\Debug`.

Comment: What you describe is missing the step of the setup project and misinterprets my issue. I deliberately included the steps in the original question. Considering we're not talking about code, I can't provide any. The best I can do is the description I've already given. When I do as you describe above, I have the same result as you. What I am  trying to do is package within a Setup Project in VS. When I install my Setup Project, I need all dependencies to be located within the bin folder which I create. The only one which isn't working is WinSCP.exe.

Comment: So you need a custom layout of the project. I still do not understand why. Why don't you take the files from the standard `bin` folder? Imo, the standard approach is to setup project take what's in the `bin` folder. -- Anyway, if you need a different layout, then do not use the NuGet package. Setup everything manually -- https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install#vs

Comment: I asked a very similar question, but focused on why it worked on my local machine but not the build server.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75110209/excludeassets-working-locally-but-not-on-build-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need a custom layout of the project. I still do not understand why. Why don't you take the files from the standard `bin` folder? Imo, the standard approach is to setup project take what's in the `bin` folder.

Anyway, if you need a different layout, then do not use the NuGet package. Setup everything manually. See [Using from Visual Studio](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install#vs) section of [Installing WinSCP .NET Assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install).