# ExcludeAssets working locally but not on build server

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild

I have a project that uses a nuget package (winscp), and that normally copies the winscp.exe to the bin folder.  I have to run the exe from another location, so that copy isn't what I am looking for (just looking to get the WinSCPnet.dll), so I exclude it using ExcludeAssets.  Which works locally, but not on my build server for some reason.

Details: I have a packagereference in my project:

```xml
  <PackageReference Include="WinSCP" Version="5.15.0">
      <!-- this prevents the exe from being copied to the bin folder (locally at least) -->
      <ExcludeAssets>build;</ExcludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
```

On my dev machine, either using msbuild or vs 2022, this correctly excludes the exe.  But when built on the build server includes the exe.  The only difference I see between my build command and the one done on the build server, is some dynamic properties and logging.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe" 
    "C:\BuildAgent\Agent01\_work\1301\s\MyApp\MyApp.vbproj" 
    /nologo /nr:false 
    /dl:CentralLogger,
   "C:\BuildAgent\Agent01\_work\_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba2196824\1.179.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"
;"RootDetailId=|SolutionDir=C:\BuildAgent\Agent01\_work\1301\s\MyApp"*ForwardingLogger,
    "C:\BuildAgent\Agent01\_work\_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba2196824\1.179.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll" 
    /p:SatelliteResourceLanguages=en-US 
    /p:OutDir=C:\BuildAgent\Agent01\_work\1301\a/MyApp
    /p:platform="AnyCPU" 
    /p:configuration="Release" 
    /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="TFS_a10cfcba-c039-4792-814d-e9ffd4de1ed7_build_314_0"
```

The MSbuild command I use locally from within the ms build bin folder:

```
   .\MSBuild.exe "C:\Users\jrmoreno\source\repos\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp.vbproj" 
    /nologo 
    /nr:false 
    /p:SatelliteResourceLanguages=en-US 
    /p:OutDir=c:/users/jrmoreno/source/MyApp
    /p:platform="AnyCPU" 
    /p:configuration="Release"
```

Comment: Does your Azure DevOps Pipelines build have a separate `nuget restore` step and if it does what version of NuGet is being used in that step?

Comment: It does and it uses Nuget 6.0.2. x64.  VS shows I have Nuget Package Manager 6.4.0

Comment: Its appears that NuGet doesn't support `ExcludeAssets`. There is an open issue; see [NuGet/Home#10907](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/10907). The `build` target should be running `restore` and I think that your local build is proof that it does. In the pipeline let MSBuild perform the `restore` by disabling the `NuGet Restore` step. (If testing shows that disabling the NuGet step resolves the issue, then remove the NuGet step.)

Comment: @JonathanDodds: the excluding seems to be a project reference thing, not a packagereference problem.  It would be weird if that was the problem, but I've seen crazier things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open bug for NuGet supporting `ExcludeAssets="build"`. See [NuGet/Home#9672](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/9672).

The `build` target should be running `restore` and I think that your local build is proof that it does. In the pipeline let MSBuild perform the `restore` by disabling or removing the `NuGet Restore` step. You could also add a step for an explicit run of `msbuild /t:restore`.

Answer (score 0):

I work rounded this by inversing "ExcludeAssets" to "IncludeAssets". Basically you list all the types you want to include: compile and etcs.